# Want to write the data as a csv format in formatting like bold , color , title using php

Tags: php, csv

I am able to write the data as a csv format but i want the data to be written ina formatted way like , there must be background color on the title field and font size must be little bit larger as compared to their regarding data.
please guide me how can  do this using php ?

Comment: @AnkiiG - adding code won't serve any particular purpose. Poster is asking for something that simply cannot be done. No matter how much code, you cannot add formatting to a CSV file

Answer (score 1):

CSV is a data only file format, does not support style formatting of any kind. If you want a file with styles (colour, bold, etc), then you need to look at a real native spreadsheet format like MS Excel's BIFF or OfficeOpenXML or Open/Libre)ffice OASIS

Comment: ohk can you please suggest me which format i should use ?

Comment: BIFF is generally the easiest, there's a lot of PHP libraries support writing to BIFF, though it's rather dated now; but OfficeOpenXML is the modern format that has been used by Excel since 2007